# How to load "dynamic" value from store to TextInput on loading and handle its onChangeText?

Tags: react-native, redux

I need to get value from store in redux to TextInput. I know it can be set by `value={this.props.Value}`. I need to save that value to save later, so I change it by using local state like this

```
value={this.state.Value}
onChangeText={text => {
  this.setState({
     Value: text
  })
}}
```

And in constructor of component, I set the value of TextInput to local state

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
  this.state = {
    Value: this.props.Value
  }
}
```

This work fine. But now, that Value is generated on loading this component.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.onLoadView();
}
```

onLoadView() will dispatch an action that generate new data of Value in store. But constructor function is called before componentDidMount(), that mean component state Value is initial data in store, not the new one. If I change it back to `value={this.props.Value}` to fix this problem, I can not handle that value to save later.

I know I can change `onChangeText` to update the value of TextInput to store immediately. But whenever I do not want to save this value, I have to change it back to the initial value. Is there any easier way to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: What value of Value does the onLoadView function store? This.state.Value? or this.props.Value?

Comment: @hongdevelop that function generate new value of Value in store, load from AsyncStorage

Comment: Cannot you do a setState inside your componentDidMount with the new value you want?

Comment: @Auticcat I can't. Because onLoadView() dispatch an action with saga to get new value from AsyncStorage. When it finishes, I update new value to store. So I don't know when it is done to setState in componentDidMount

Comment: Did you try with componentDidUpdate? It should update trigger and you can use prevProps to check if the value has been updated in your props

Comment: @Auticcat you are right! componentDidUpdate can solve my problem. It is perfectly for me. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comment, you can use `componentDidUpdate` to check your previous props and comparing them to the ones you are using in your component:

```
componentDidUpdate = () => {
   if(this.props.Value !== this.state.Value) this.setState({Value : this.props.Value })
}
```

As you are storing the previous `props.Value` in your state you can directly compare the current props with the current state